# How do I select debug vs release libraries automatically?

Tags: c#, debugging, configuration, release, libraries

Using MS Visual Studio 2008, I created a C# library (let's call it main.dll) that relies on a second library (helper.dll).  In the Debug version of main.dll, I set a reference to the debug version of helper.dll.  But when I switch to build the Release version of main.dll, the output folder still includes the debug version of helper.dll.  I do not see a way to select different versions of helper.dll for different build types.  In C++, I could tell the linker what folder to get its files from, but I don't see a way to do that for C#.

Comment: You essentially changed your question in the comment you added on Dan Puzey's answer, then downvoted our answers because they don't match the new details added.  That is poor form.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way of doing this is to have all of your projects in a single solution, and use project references between them.  Then, when you build in Debug, all components will be built and referenced as debug - and likewise for Release.

Alternatively, you can use a single output folder for all your assemblies, reference each binary from there, and ensure that the build order is correct - so that your `helper.dll` is built to that folder before `main.dll` is built.  This is more prone to failure, though, and requires a greater amount of manual maintenance.

Comment: I really dislike having all my projects in one solution because main.dll is going to be used in multiple solutions.  That's the whole reason I started thinking about this.  If Solution1 uses project Main, then it must use project Helper.  I don't want to do that.  I want to tell Solution1 to use project Main, and have project Main automatically bring along the correct version of project Helper.

Oh, well.  It's not that big a deal, and if I try to get fancy, I'll just end up confusing co-workers.

Thanks very much for replying.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch from Debug to Release, Visual Studio switches from Debug to Release in the bin folder for the output.

Set the "Copy Always" property to true for main.dll.  This will insure that it gets copied to the appropriate output folder, and is always referenced.

Answer (score 0):

If the second library `helper.dll` is being built at the same time in the same solution, you can use a Project reference instead of referencing the .dll directly.  Then, you can set up a solution-level configuration for `Release` mode, and build both projects in `Release` mode that way.